# Reconnect Shutdown Redis Instance back to Cluster

Tags: redis

Given a redis cluster with six nodes (3M/3S) on ports 7000-7005 with master nodes on ports 7000-7002 and slave nodes on the rest, master node 7000 is shut down, so node 7003 becomes the new master:

```
$ redis-cli -p 7003 cluster nodes
2a23385e94f8a27e54ac3b89ed3cabe394826111 127.0.0.1:7004 slave 1108ef4cf01ace085b6d0f8fd5ce5021db86bdc7 0 1452648964358 5 connected
5799de96ff71e9e49fd58691ce4b42c07d2a0ede 127.0.0.1:7000 master,fail - 1452648178668 1452648177319 1 disconnected
dad18a1628ded44369c924786f3c920fc83b59c6 127.0.0.1:7002 master - 0 1452648964881 3 connected 10923-16383
dfcb7b6cd920c074cafee643d2c631b3c81402a5 127.0.0.1:7003 myself,master - 0 0 7 connected 0-5460
1108ef4cf01ace085b6d0f8fd5ce5021db86bdc7 127.0.0.1:7001 master - 0 1452648965403 2 connected 5461-10922
bf60041a282929cf94a4c9eaa203a381ff6ffc33 127.0.0.1:7005 slave dad18a1628ded44369c924786f3c920fc83b59c6 0 1452648965926 6 connected
```

How does one go about [automatically] reconnecting/restarting node 7000 as a slave instance of 7003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redis Cluster: Re-adding a failed over node](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2462) has detail explanation about what happens.

Basically, the node will become a slave of the slave (which is now a master) that replaced it during the failover.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Redis Sentinel Documentation](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel)?

> Redis Sentinel provides high availability for Redis. In practical
>   terms this means that using Sentinel you can create a Redis deployment
>   that resists without human intervention to certain kind of failures.